# Need a shell script for creating users along with password

Tags: linux

I would like to create users with password using shell script?

i tried on google but not worked. could you some one please share a script.

Comment: Couple comments.  When you create a new question, make sure you format it so the code is clearly identifiable and with good indentation.  Another point, instead of using ` `` ` to execute commands, use `$()`.  It is also a good idea to use double quotes around variable extensions.   Sometimes you do it, sometimes you dont.

Comment: use `chpasswd` to change password in batch scripts

Comment: if you do `man passwd` you will see that the `--stdin` does not exist for that command.